# Resetting a static counter vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel workbook where the user imports data. I have a static counter to count how many imports were completed. Code for counter.. This macro gets called each time the user imports a data set.

```
Public Sub Macro()
Static i As Integer
Worksheets("Hidden").Activate

i = i + 1

Cells(i + 1, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & i

Cells(2, 2).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & i

End Sub
```

Now if the user clears all data in the sheet by pressing the "Clear Data" button I want the static counter to reset. Any idea on how to code this? I have been looking online and have not found an answer! TIA

Comment: Add an optional boolean "reset" parameter which defaults to false: call `Macro True` to reset the counter.

Answer (score 3):

Add an optional Boolean "reset" parameter which defaults to False: call `Macro True` to reset the counter.

```
Public Sub Macro(Optional reset As Boolean = False)

    Static i As Integer
    If reset Then
        i = 0
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Worksheets("Hidden").Activate

    i = i + 1

    Cells(i + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & i

    Cells(2, 2).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & i

End Sub
```

Comment: I also thought of it. but problem is, it's no longer a traditional "macro" is it? I mean if it's to be launched from GUI, as its name indicates. but it might a just a coincidence though :)

Comment: I don't think there's a real distinction to be made here - "macro" is kind of a generic term used to cover a bunch of "automation"-type things. To me, adding a parameter to a method doesn't represent a fundamental change.

Comment: I agree fundamentally. It's just the OP's choice of the name that puzzled me :D

Comment: How can i modify the above code.. I do want it to reset to zero if the clear all data button is selected but then I want to count the i's all over again!

Comment: I tried to just get rid of the Exit Sub but then after clearing all data and rerunning my code i = 2

Comment: If you just call `Macro` without passing `True` it will behave the same as your original code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a Static variable, you would have to use a Public variable (declared outside of the routine) - that's the only way other macros can 'see' it.

```
Public i As Integer

Public Sub Macro()
Worksheets("Hidden").Activate

i = i + 1

Cells(i + 1, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & i

Cells(2, 2).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & i

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok so then how do I set i = 0 when the clear data button is selected?

Comment: clear it in the same routine that clears the cells in the worksheet

Comment: fyi: do not use _activate_ ... _select_ ... _activecell_ . use  `Worksheets("Hidden").Cells(i + 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & i`

Comment: How to clear it? make the code for you button this: `i = 0`

Comment: In my clear data button code i have entered Set i = 0 but get an error: ambiguous name detected: ?

Comment: dont use `Set` - that is for objects, not variables.

Comment: still get ambiguous name detected when i just put i = 0

Comment: are both macros in the same module/form?